# Node.js call parent method in class

Tags: node.js, class, events

I am trying to emit an event inside a class.

But I can't find a way to call the parent method.

Please see the comment lines to understand what I'm trying to do.

This is my VirtualChart.js

```
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
const EventEmitter = require("events");

class VirtualChart extends EventEmitter {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.client = new WebSocketClient();

        this.client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
            console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
        });

        this.client.on('connect', function(connection) {

            console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');

            connection.on('error', function(error) {
                console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
            });

            connection.on('close', function() {
                console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
            });

            connection.on('message', function(message) {
                if (message.type === 'utf8') {
                    console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
                    this.emit("newMessage", message.utf8Data);//here is the problem
                    //this.parent.emit("newMessage", message.utf8Data);??????
                    //this.parent.parent.emit("newMessage", message.utf8Data);??????
                }
            });
        });

        this.client.connect('wss://myurl.com');

    }

}
```

And this is my main.js

```
var VirtualChart = require('./VirtualChart');

var virtualChart = new VirtualChart();

virtualChart.on("newMessage", (param) => {

    console.log("newMessage " + param);

});
```

Comment: There is no separate parent object.  When you subclass, you create ONE object that has a combined set of methods and properties from the base class.  Subclass methods of the same name will override base class methods. So, `this.emit()` is how you call the `.emit()` method that comes from the base EventEmitter class.  If you had overridden `emit()` in the subclass and you wanted to explicitly call the  base class' version of emit from within a subclass method, you can do `super.emit()`, but that can only be done from within a subclass method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I do see one problem.  The value of `this` in `this.emit()` is probably wrong because it is set by the `connection.on()` handler and will not point to your object. You can fix that my using an arrow function for your callback instead of a plain function.

Change this:

```
    this.client.on('connect', function(connection) {

        console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');

        connection.on('error', function(error) {
            console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
        });

        connection.on('close', function() {
            console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
        });

        connection.on('message', function(message) {
            if (message.type === 'utf8') {
                console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
                this.emit("newMessage", message.utf8Data);
            }
        });
    });
```

to this (which uses arrow functions for the callbacks):

```
    this.client.on('connect', connection => {

        console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');

        connection.on('error', error => {
            console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
        });

        connection.on('close', () => {
            console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
        });

        connection.on('message', message => {
            if (message.type === 'utf8') {
                console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
                this.emit("newMessage", message.utf8Data);
            }
        });
    });
```

The arrow functions will preserve the lexical value of `this`.  The regular `function(...)` callbacks will not and the value of `this` will be set by the caller of the callback (which knows nothing about your object).